# Can't read tiny barcode through ZXing library

Tags: android, camera, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have recently made an app to detect barcodes using the ZXing library. It works well but the problem is that **it can't read very small barcodes and sometimes delays approximately more than 4 seconds to read it**. The size of these barcodes is 18 mm for width and 6 mm for the height on some products. I tried with a Samsung Note 4 device.
**Is there any way or modify some values in the library that help to read fast for at most 1 or 2 seconds**?

Comment: I have suffered a lot from this and it depends on the accuracy of the camera and the intensity of light in the place. Your hand must be fixed when reading bar code

Comment: @HazemENG thanks for your response. It is true that it depends on that. But I am asking about other factors help to improve it such preview size or FPS. Is there a better ratio to set it for better performance –